# onchange function gets triggered when setting value via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Testing my HTML5 app I ran into the following problem:

When my app finished loading the following jquery function is executed

```
// Sets the Dropdownvalue and sliders according to the values in the local storage
function setDropdownAndSliders() {
    // Set the filters to localally stored values
    var minAge = getItem("minAge");
    var maxAge = getItem("maxAge");
    var gend   = getItem("showGend");
    var orient = getItem("showOrient");
    var verf   = getItem("verf");

    // FILTER SETTINGS
    $("#filterGender").val(gend).change();
    $("#filterOrient").val(orient).change();
    $("#verified").val(verf).change();
    $("#settings").page();
    $("#rangeMin").val(minAge);
    $("#rangeMax").val(maxAge);
    $("#rangeMin").slider('refresh');
    $("#rangeMax").slider('refresh');
}
```

What this function does, is setting the selected value of some `<select>` elements, to the values stored in local Storage. (The function `getItem(string)` is also written by me to access local Storage values)

Now the html elements look like this:

```
<select name="filterGender" id="filterGender" onchange="onChangeGender()">
  <option value="male">Male</option>
  <option value="female">Female</option>
  <option value="both">Both</option>
</select>
```

---

**My Problem:**

Every time the function `setDropdownAndSliders()` is executed and the values of the `<select>` are set to those stored in LocalStorage, the onchange Handler of the `<select>` elements is triggered and additional functions are executed, which should only be triggered when the user manually changes the dropdown menu.

In some cases functions are executed which even invoke Ajax calls, which  obviously results into unecessary loading time, when the web app is loaded.

---

How could I change the code so that the onchange functions are NOT called when the value of the `<select>` elements in change via jquery?

Comment: You're manually triggering the change event with `.change()`, so why wouldn't that happen ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove the .change(); in the end of your command:

replace:

```
$("#filterGender").val(gend).change();
```

by:

```
$("#filterGender").val(gend);
```

Comment: wow such an easy fix, thanks! I really can't remember why i added the .change(); in the first place hm.

Answer (score 1):

Before you modify every element, disable them :

```
document.getElementById("filterGender").disabled = true;
```

At the end, enable them:

```
document.getElementById("filterGender").disabled = false;
```